# How to create an array of objects In PHP using a while loop

Tags: php

Hi so I am attempting to return all the "people" from my database and then create an object of the "person" data, then at the end of each while loop add the person to the array. Outside of the while loop i am then encoding said array.

Below attached is my current code:

```
class person {
   public $firstName = "";
   public $lastName = "";
}

$people = array();
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM People");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $firstName=$row['firstName'];
      $lastName=$row['lastName'];

      $e = new Person();        
      $e->firstName  = $firstName;
      $e->lastName = $lastName;

      array_push($people, $e);
}

json_encode($people);
```

Many thanks

Comment: And are you having any particular problem?

Comment: What is your question, friend?

Comment: My question is why isn't the code above working i guess

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be a question here, but perhaps [mysqli_fetch_object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) would be more useful to you in this case.

Also, watch your naming. You've called your class "person" and instantiated it as "Person". PHP is rather flexible about case, but this could lead to issues later on in your program.

Lastly, `json_encode` just encodes an object. If you want to display the result or push it to the browser for consumption, you'll need to echo it out:

```php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($people);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "**mysqli_fetch_assoc**" instead of "**mysqli_fetch_array**" if you want to use an associative approach.

```
class Person 
{
   public $firstName = null;
   public $lastName  = null;
}

$people = array();
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `People`");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $e = new Person();        

      $e->firstName = $row['firstName'];
      $e->lastName  = $row['lastName'];   
}

json_encode($people);
```